# Unable to start Apache HTTPD after server reboot

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf, rhel

unable to start Apache HTTPD after server reboot. We have /etc/httpd/conf/ owned by func. user/group. Hence we use scripts to start httpd.conf and every time server reboots, we are unable to start HTTPD. We found that /var/run/httpd is getting changed to apache/root after reboot. Hence script fails to start the HTTPD which is under func. user/group.

Please help me !!!

Comment: How did you try to start the service? service apache2 start? What Linux you run? What is the error you get?

Comment: I have RHEL 7 and inside /etc/httpd/conf, I start it using a shell script and the command is /usr/sbin/httpd -k start. Failed to start httpd.

Comment: Please take a look into your syslog or error.log of your httpd ... also look if there is a old apache2.pid on your system .... you must search for the error in the log files and than post the output

Comment: Share below  command output `1) systemctl start httpd` `2) systemctl status  httpd`  `3) httpd -t`

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server and I am getting the below error when I try start HTTPD:
[auth_digest:error] [pid 2351:tid 1396820191726976] (13) Permission denied: AH01762: Failed to create shared memory segment on file /run/httpd/authdigest_shm.2351
AH01760: failed to initialize shm - all nonce-count checking and one-time noncesdisabled
AH00020: Configuration failed, exiting

Comment: 1) systemctl start httpd - I cant run this command in a func. user, I am using a shell script with command /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf -k start 2) yes httpd is running in root user 3) HTTPD syntax OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DefaultRuntimeDir directive to override the default "/run/httpd" directory. This goes in httpd.conf. For example:

```
DefaultRuntimeDir  "/my/local/rundir"
```

This will cause apache to create "/my/local/rundir/authdigest_shm.1234"

For some reason this doesn't also override the default pid file directory, so set it with the PidFile directive, e.g.:

```
PidFile "/my/local/rundir/httpd.pid"
```

Use `/my/local/rundir/` location to your location which contains  user/group permission.If you dont want to change location then you can use below configuration in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/httpd.conf`

```
d /var/run/httpd   700 myuser mygroup
d /var/run/httpd/htcacheclean   700 myuser mygroup
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Donald123 and Pandurang, Worked like a charm... !!!